# Windows 8.1 - How to open a batch from a batch with different admin privileges?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, batch-file

I must run a bat which calls a program. Problem is I need to run the BAT as admin and call the program WITHOUT admin. I don't know why but it I call the program as admin it gives me a path error when it opens the program, which doesn't happens if I call it without admin privileges.

So my idea is to run another batch file called form inside the first batch so that batch runs without admin privileges, but didn't work.

In resume:

Run the program calling it with full path:

call c:\estetica\estetica.exe

-> error of missing files

Run the program using just estetica.exe (the bat file is in the same dir as the program)

No errors.

Run the program as ADMIN:

Error.

Run the program running the BAT file without admin privilegies:

Perfect.

So what makes the thing work is RUN the program NOT opening the BATCH file as admin AND run it using just the program name.

Batch file:

```
SET CUR_DATE=%DATE%
DATE 05/12/2013
START estetica.exe
TIMEOUT 5
DATE %CUR_DATE%
```

Comment: Better idea: How about you post details about the program you're running, and the error you're getting, so that we might perhaps be able to help you troubleshoot that problem instead of working around it? Also, are you familiar at all with `runas`? Seems that should simply solve your issue, if your proposed workaround will work at all.

Comment: -1 Give the command line you are using

Comment: it's a program from a small company here, so no ones know it for sure. I've tried runas, using a non-admin account, and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @barlop Everything is in OP. Why -1

Comment: @FernandoSBS I have removed my -1 as now you included that

Comment: Does this help? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hgWF9pK1  shows use of runas command, you can run a program as whatever user  put echo %userprofile% in the bat file to see the user profile. and you can replace the cmd /k c:\blah\a.bat, with  asdf.exe `runas /user:Administrator c:\windows\system32\calc.exe`

Comment: I've tried the RUNAS not to run as admin but to run as non-admin the part that has problems with admin. Do you think I could use the commands SET CUR_DATE and DATE as admin with runas?

Comment: Does this command change the date for you? It does for me, tested in win7 `runas /user:Administrator "cmd.exe /k date 30/09/2222"`

Comment: that does work, but to be a functional option I would need the CMD windows to autoclose and a way to run it without having to type in the password for the user each time. any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding to your .bat file a `cd` command like `cd /d c:\estetica\`?

Please post the exact error messages you're getting.

`call` is not really supposed to be used to run .exe files, only batch files.

Comment: Ok but it's the same if I call exe with CALL or without CALL (just path). If you see the original post you will see that I speak about using CD command, dunno if you have takken that in account sorry.

Comment: if you don't have rep to post comment to your question, you can you perhaps edit your existing answer adding your replies to that? or comment on your answer if you can comment there? it's not good to post multiple comment answers, i'm sure it's unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

Re the path error, you probably need to give the full path to the program (e.g., C:\Something\SomethingElse\program.exe not just program.exe).

Comment: Remember to encapsulate the full path in double quotes if there are spaces in the full path (e.g. C:\program files)

Comment: That's also produces error, if I run the program with the full path it's gives another type of error, also about not finding files. No spaces in the full path. I've add some more info in the OP